# Loopback(express) respond to request with other's access-token

Tags: node.js, express, authorization, loopbackjs

Sometimes when there are more than one person logged into the system, It's appeared to have an issue: on the profile page, it doesn't show my user but the other's. After I refresh the page, It's back to normal, shows the correct user info.

My program use access-token for authorization so I decided to respond to profile page's request with access-token in order to check if it is the same at the browser. And it turns out that sometimes it is, sometimes it's not. What may cause this problem?

```
// routes.js

/**
 * I include this middleware just in case
 * but I don't think It's the cause.
 */ 
app.use('/login', function(req, res, next) {
    if(!req.cookies.Authorization) {
        return next();
    }

    AccessToken.findOne(
        { where: { id: req.cookies.Authorization}},
        onFoundAccessToken
    );

    function onFoundAccessToken(err, access_token) {
        if(err || !access_token) {
            return next();
        }
        res.redirect('/app/agenda');
    }
});


/**
 * profile page route handler
 */ 
app.get('/app/profile', function(req, res) {
    var Session = app.models.Session;
    AccessToken.findOne(
        { where: { id: req.cookies.Authorization}},
        onFoundAccessToken
    );

    function onFoundAccessToken(err, accessToken) {
        if(err || !accessToken) {
            return res
                .status(403)
                .redirect('/login');
        }

        accessToken.user(onFoundUser);
    }

    function onFoundUser(err, user) {
        if(err || !user) {
            console.log(err || 'no user found');
        }

        var data = {
            scripts: ['profile.js'],
            user: user,
            /**
             * accessToken is returned to client
             * in order to check if it's the same
             * as the one stored in the cookie at
             * the browser
             */
            accessToken: req.cookies.Authorization
        };

        res.render('pages/profile', data);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out that there's nothing wrong with the code. I tested it on production environment over the internet and there's an ISP cache which sometimes handle request instead of the production server.

So I add:

```
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" />
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" />
```

to tell any ISP and browsers not to cache this page.

ref: [How to control web page caching, across all browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49547/making-sure-a-web-page-is-not-cached-across-all-browsers)